# How to subset data within function using rlang verbs?

Tags: r, rlang

I'm trying loop over several plots and combine them into a cowplot::plot_grid. I can't feed a list of plots to the plot_grid function directly because I am customizing the plots so that only one y-axis is displayed per row.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sjPlot)
library(rlang)
data(mtcars)
model <- lm(hp ~ cyl + mpg, data = mtcars)
plotlist <- map(c("cyl", "mpg"), function(x) plot_model(model, type = "pred", terms = {{x}}) )
combine_plots <- function(plotlist) {
  plot_grid(plotlist[[1]],   
            plotlist[[2]] + 
              theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                    axis.title.y = element_blank() ))
}
map(plotlist, function(x) combine_plots(enquo(x)))
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error `Error in x[["plot.list"]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable`. I presume that I'm using the wrong quasiquotation verb. How can I correct the error?

Comment: In general you’d just replace `enquo(x)` with `x` — there’s no need for non-standard evaluation here. But in fact, the entire last line needs to be replaced by `combine_plots(plotlist)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not as familiar with `sjPlot`'s plot layout, but this could be done in `patchwork` thusly:

```
combine_plots <- function(plotlist) {
  patchwork::plot_layout(
    plotlist[[1]] |
    plotlist[[2]] + 
      theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
            axis.title.y = element_blank() ))
}

combine_plots(plotlist)
```

[image]

(I kept the OP code which does not align the y axes, but you might want to be explicit about the y axis so that the two plots align, e.g. with `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,250))`